# Протестантски(-)предвзятый

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Как правильно написать — с дефисом или без?

> Ограниченный протестантски(-)предвзятыми традициями.

Answer (score 3):

Раздельное написание наречия и прилагательного (значение уподобления для наречия: как у протестантов):

**ограниченный протестантски предвзятыми традициями.**

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49#pp49

Примечание. Обычно отдельно пишутся наречия на -ски, в сочетании с прилагательным характеризующие признак **путем уподобления,** выделяющие, подчеркивающие его в каком-либо отношении:

ангельски кроткое отношение,
детски наивные высказывания,
практически ненужное новшество,
рабски покорная готовность,
теоретически важная проблема,
товарищески чуткое внимание,
фанатически слепая преданность,
химически чистый состав,
энциклопедически разносторонние знания,
юридически сложный случай и т. п.

ПРЕДВЗЯТЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -взят, -а, -о. Сложившийся заранее, до ознакомления с кем-, чем-л., без учёта действительных фактов; пристрастный.

Comment: спасибо, но, прочитав Розенталя, позволю себе не согласиться с вами, сославшись на следующий пример: «мещански-провинциальные манеры (‘провинциальные с оттенком мещанства’) — мещански провинциальные манеры (‘по-мещански провинциальные’)». В обсуждаемом вопросе, очевидно, ситуация таки дефисная.

Comment: Через дефис пишутся сложные прилагательные, образованные сложением основ двух прилагательных. Мещански-провинциальные манеры - это  два прилагательных, из которых первое обозначает оттенок второго. Кстати, различить семантику вариантов в этом примере достаточно сложно, между ними даже могут быть однородные отношения. В Вашем случае выбор более ответственный. Фактически это "протестантские предвзятые традиции" при дефисном написании. Вы выбираете протестантский оттенок для предвзятых традиций, а не предвзятые, как у протестантов, традиции.  И это Ваш выбор, так как тема Вам известна.